# Change icon and icon color automatically based on command in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

I just wondering if in VS Code has this kind of customization whereas when we execute a command in terminal then the color and the icon will change accordingly. for example as in picture shown, when I run `ng serve` and the title of the terminal tab will be `ng` and the icon and color will change automatically (in this picture, I manually change it).

what I found from my research (in google) is just terminal profile and it's not answering my curiosity.

[image: description]

Comment: have a look at the source and create a Pull Request

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [terminal profile](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_configuring-profiles) and set the property `overrideName` to true, you can set a color if you like.